# How to Pass a Tuple as a Keyword Argument (kwarg)

Tags: python

I have a pair of functions which take keyword arguments, as follows:

```
def update(self, uri, **properties):
    self._req("POST", uri, properties)

def _req(self, method, frag, data=None):
    resp = requests.request(method, self.url + frag,
                            data=json.dumps(data, default=_json_serial),
                            verify=self.verify,
                            auth=self.credentials,
                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

I'm a little unclear on how exactly this happens, but the functionality is as follows: I call `update(uri, status=1)` and it passes down to `_req()` as a dict.

As part of my program, I want to write a function like this:

```
def updateIP(uri, **kwargs):        
    for d in kwargs.items(): 
        swis.update(uri, **dict([d])))

updateIP(uri='orion.x.com', status=1, sysname="test")
```

Now, as written it works fine, but that bit at the end with casting it as a dict looks ugly as sin. Is there a cleaner way to do it? If I just pass it as `**d` it gives me the error `builtins.TypeError: update() argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple`

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling `updateIP` with key-value pairs `status=1, sysname="test"` , similarly you should call swis.update() with key-value pairs.

The way you are looping:

```
for d in kwargs.items():
```

gives you a pair(tuple) which isn't the way you pass keyword arguments.

You can rather pass the dictionary as it is.

Eg.

```
def updateIP(uri, **kwargs):        
    for d in kwargs: 
        swis.update(uri,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that pass the **entire argument set** to `update()`, once for each keyword pair? I need to pass one k,v pair at a time to the function.

Comment: In that case, you have to pass in a way that a key=value is passed.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def updateIP(uri, **kwargs):        
    for k, v in kwargs.items(): 
        swis.update(uri, **{k: v})
```

It's sad that you can't `POST` all `properties` in one go with `swis.update(uri, **kwargs)`.